# Fixed header, DIV sitting behind not under

Tags: html, css

I have a small problem if anyone can help. I'm probably being really stupid but I can't seem to get my DIV to sit under my fixed header as it's currently sitting behind.

```
</body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
        </div>
        <div class="home">
            <img src="images/home.jpg" alt="" height="563" width="760">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

body {
    text-align: center;
}

#container {
    width: 760px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#header {
    padding-top: 250px;
    position: fixed;
    background-image: url(images/logo.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 40%;
}

.home {
}
```

Edit: another thing to not is in the header there is a basic CSS menu, didn't think the code was necessary for this issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Positioning absolute/fixed takes the div out of the flow of the document. To get the `.home` to sit below the header you would need to give it `margin-top` equal to the height of the header

Comment: Interestingly I thought this was the case, and the fix. Just tried it, and the margin-top to home moves the #header down too. Doesn't make any sense. But padding-top doesn't, why would this be?

Comment: I think its better to not use margin-top because firefox will double the margin-top value. An alternative is to use padding-top in stead of margin-top and use the same value for it. Or you could add an empty element bofore the .home and set the width the same as .home + a height of 250px. But i prefer to use padding-top if possible to prevent usage of unnescessary elements.